# FirebaseMessagingService cannot override zzae(Intent) in zzb. Weaker reference error

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am currently using firebase-messaging 9.4.0 and there is an error while building the application I got an error saying

`Error:(18, 8) error: zzae(Intent) in FirebaseMessagingService cannot override zzae(Intent) in zzb
attempting to assign weaker access privileges; was protected`

So I inspected the compiled FirebaseMessagingService which was the subclass of `com.google.firebase.iid.zzb`and had zzae(Intent) method as private but its subclass `FirebaseMessagingService` had protected access I know that subclasses cannot have weaker reference than its super class so I guess there is something wrong with FirebaseMessagingService library.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I got the same today i changed play-services to 9.8.0 but i had firebase still at 9.4.0, changing firebase to use 9.8.0 solved it.

Comment: Yeah changing it to 9.8.0 worked for me too but for some reason I can't do that with my project right now. It seems to be a problem with this version only

Answer (score 0):

If you have updated your gradle version of firebase just sync once.
Firebase version and playservices should be same